# SELECT dates not matching any element

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this record on DDBB:

[image: database]

And want to select any record having the date "2014 -06 -02" between its cl_startDate date and its cl_endDate date (this means record ID 39 should be selected). For this  I do it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM class_conf
WHERE ( 2014 -06 -02 >= cl_startDate ) && ( 2014 -06 -02 <= cl_endDate )
```

Theorically, this should select any record with a cl_startDate and a cl_endDate between the given date, but it results on 0 matches selected.

I have also tried this ways:

```
SELECT *
FROM class_conf
WHERE 2014 -06 -02 >= cl_startDate &&2014 -06 -02 <= cl_endDate


SELECT *
FROM class_conf
WHERE (cl_startDate <=2014 -06 -02) && ( cl_endDate >=2014 -06 -02 )
```

all resulting on 0 records

Comment: Why don't you use the `BETWEEN` operator? `cl_startDate BETWEEN x AND y`

Comment: Your title says "dates not matching", but your question is about "dates between". Which is it?

Comment: Between is another way of getting the correct records. Is there any advantage between using operator method and between method?

Comment: The logic is more obvious when you use `BETWEEN`.

Comment: Oops, it should be `'xxx' BETWEEN cl_startDate AND cl_endDate`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to put your dates in quotes otherwise you're doing math operations. Also, no spaces in your date values. You also want o use `AND` and not `&&`. The parenthesis are not necessary here.

```
SELECT * FROM class_conf
WHERE '2014-06-02' >= cl_startDate AND '2014-06-02' <= cl_endDate
```

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have spaces between your dates?

```
SELECT * FROM class_conf
WHERE ( 2014 -06 -02 >= cl_startDate ) && ( 2014 -06 -02 <= cl_endDate )
```

This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM class_conf
WHERE ('2014-06-02' >= cl_startDate AND '2014-06-02' <= cl_endDate)
```

Note how the dates have the spaces removed, have single quotes (`'`) around them, the `&&` is now an `AND` and there is no need for separate parenthesis around each condition in this case, so I just left one surrounding the whole `( [something AND [another thing] )` statement.

Comment: There's no need for any parentheses at all.